# How do i export the whole canvas of the layer with photoshop "export as" feature

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, canvas

Im trying to find the most efficient way to export a lot of layers in to jpgs with a specific size, but the layers have differently sized artworks in them. When using "Export as" on the layers they will only export the visible artwork in the layer and ignore the canvas size.

I.E. i have 10 layers with differently sized artworks on a canvas of 1000x1000px, i want to just export the layers as 1000x1000px jpgs but they are exported as each individual artwork size instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export each layer into a separate jpeg (or other format) you need to go to

**File** -> **Scripts** -> **Export Layers to Files..** like so:

Tested with exporting to jpeg and it will keep the size of your document when exporting :

[image]

This is what it exported (Two 1000x1000px files) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was not a default script so i had to download, but it was exactly what i needed. I wish adobes own "export as" function wasn't so clunky and lacking in options.